# Are there any issues with submitting conference papers in one language and publishing them in a journal in a different language?

Tags: publications, ethics

I have some research I want to present at a conference in my native language but I would rather submit for publication in English after finalizing it. Are there any ethical issues with this I am missing?

Comment: Are you in CS/computer engineering? That would be relevant information because they treat conference publications differently than the rest of academia.

Comment: It's interdisciplinary. Expecting it will be similar to rest of the academia vs submitting on IEEE/ACM

Comment: How obscure is your native language?  (This is for practical issues, not ethical ones.)

Comment: By the standards of your discipline, would it be ethical if they were in the same language?  If yes, then you're fine.  If no, then the second publication needs to make clear that it's a translated and extended version of the first, you may need the permission of the conference publisher, and you shouldn't "count" them as two separate publications.

Comment: @NateEldredge this is the answer.

Comment: @NateEldredge Please don't write answers in comments.

Comment: I was hoping OP would answer the question about the standards of their discipline.  Then I or someone else could write a more focused answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments. It is totally irrelevant if they are in two languages. If it would be ethical to do this one language then it will be ethical in two. If it is unethical in one language then it will be unethical in two. In my field presenting at a conference and then submitting a paper to a journal is just fine, as long as the conference does not publish a *proceedings* or similar. In other fields, it is not acceptable. Again, the language matters not.